# When calling a static integer from a different class, it is losing it's value and defaulting to zero?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, static, integer

I'm trying to call a static integer from one class to another.  This integer is called successfully, but the value is zero instead of the value from the original class.

I've tried quite a few things getting to this point, but now am stuck.  I'm assuming this issue is a rookie mistake.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In Class1...

```
public static int countSAO;
...
countSAO = SAO_Num.count;
```

after this, countSAO has a value of 9017.  In other class...

```
button.Text = Class1.countSAO.toString();
```

the button text is 0 instead of the expected 9017.

Larger chunk of code(Class1).

```
class Class1
{

public static List<String> SAO_Num = new List<String>();
... //Create the SAO lists that show up in the while loop.

public void InitializeSaoStars()
    {
...
 while ((line = fileSAO.ReadLine()) != "#End")
                {                        
                    string[] items = line.Split('\t'); //Store strings into aray.  Items seperated by tabs.
                    //Add to our lists, items[0] and items[1] are to be skipped per the file.
                    SAO_BayerLetter.Add(items[2]);
                    SAO_Constellation.Add(items[3]);
                    SAO_Num.Add(items[4]);
                    SAO_CoordRA.Add(items[5]);
                    SAO_CoordDec.Add(items[6]);
                    SAO_Magnitude.Add(items[7]);
                    SAO_SpectralType.Add(items[8]);
                    SAO_Distance.Add(items[9]);
                    SAO_ProperName.Add(items[10]);
                    SAO_AutoCalFlag.Add(items[11]);

                }
...
textBox1.Text = SAO_Num.Count.ToString();// this is 9017
...
public static int MyCountSAOValue()
    {

        return SAO_Num.Count;
    }
```

That is all from Class1.

Here is me calling the MyCountSAOValue method in Class2.

```
public partial class Class2: UserControl
{
    public UserControlTelescope()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button.Text = UserControlRotator.MyCountSAOValue().ToString();//This sets the button text to 0.
```

Comment: Can you provide relevant portions of your code?

Comment: Done. Sorry for not having it posted originally.

Comment: Are you sure the value is assigned to the field _before_ the field is assigned to the button?

Comment: That's a good question. Actually I'm not sure.  I'll look into that.  Seems promising.  Thank you.

Comment: There are 2 ways to make this work, 1) assign the value in the calling class before assigning it to button.Text or 2) adding a function in Class1 where you get value from a function. Please see my answer.

Comment: In Class1 you should remove the textBox1.Text = SAO_Num.Count.ToString();// this is 9017

Answer (score 1):

This should help you find the order in which the count is called.
   Just replace:

```
public static List<String> SAO_Num = new List<String>();
```

by:

```
 public static List<string> sao_num = new List<string>();
 public static List<string> SAO_Num {
            get {
                Console.WriteLine("Grabbing value of SAO_NUM: " + (sao_num == null ? "null" : "" + sao_num.Count));
                return sao_num;
            }
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Setting value of SAO_NUM to: " + (value == null ? "null" : "" + value.Count));
                sao_num = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You must assign button text in Class2 not in Class1 (remove the line in Class1 where you are setting button text as well).

```
public static class Class1
{
    // simulate reading lines from file
    public static List<String> SAO_Num = new List<String>() {
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3",
        "test4",
        "test5",
        "test6",
        "test7",
        "test8",
        "test9",
        "test10"
    };

    public static int countSAO = SAO_Num?.Count ?? 0;
}

public class Class2
{
    ...
    button.Text = Class1.countSAO.ToString();
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works if I explicitly set countSAO to 9017.  However, if I say 

countSAO = SAO_Num.count; it still returns 0.

Comment: Then the root cause of your issue is the value of SAO_Num.Count. Make sure SAO_Num.Count has the proper value.

Comment: It does.  I can print SAO_Num.Count from Class1 and get 9017.  Within Class1, if I create a class and return SAO_Num.Count; then call it from Class2, it will print 0.

Comment: Can you include SAO_Num in the code you provided? I assume it is another property of Class1 and that it is some sort of collection?

Comment: Is that larger chunk of code part of Class1 or the other class?

Comment: Class1. Only part of the other class is the last line of the post.

Comment: Code updated. Basically simulating reading lines of from file here in Class1.

Comment: Honestly I don't find a need for the property countSAO here. Just return SAO_Num.Count will do.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  countSAO will, likely, come into play later but it serves no purpose currently.  I'm still returning 0.  I set the return type for MyCountSAOValue() to string just to try something; that's also returning 0.  Could it matter that this is a winforms project?  I suck for no stating this earlier.

Comment: So I just made some minor changes in Class1. Define SAO_Num list first then set the value of countSAO to SAO_Num.Count. Then in your other class, set the button text to Class1.countSAO. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Static members (variables, properties, methods) can be accessed directly. If you try to access countSAO without changing it, it will return 0.

You will need to update the value before using it. You can either use the class constructor or have a static property that will update it.

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int beforeInstantiation = Class1.countSAO; // output: 0

    Class1 myclass = new Class1();

    int afterInstantiation = Class1.countSAO; // output: 9017

    Class1.updatedCount(); // update the Static variable before calling

    int updatedSao = Class1.countSAO; // output 500

    int saoProperty = Class1.countSAOProperty; // output 9017
}

class Class1
{
    public static int countSAO; // this would not 

    public static int countSAOProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return SAO_Num.Count;
        }
    }

    // this will be called only when the class is instantiated using New Class1();
    public static List<int> SAO_Num
    {
        get
        {
            List<int> intlist = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 9017; i++)
            {
                intlist.Add(i);
            }

            return intlist;
        }
    }
    // this will only run if class is Instantiate using New Class();
    public Class1()
    {
        countSAO = SAO_Num.Count;
    }

    public static void updatedCount()
    {
        countSAO = 500;
    }
}
```